# Moving Uploaded Images From Tmp Folder?

Tags: php, upload

Moving Uploaded Images From Tmp Folder?

I am following a tutorial to store images into a folder on a server.

Unless I'm mistaken when doing this images are always first stored into a temporary folder then moved. The problem is I'm using shared hosting so I don't know where the tmp folder is so I get this error :

Could not move /tmp/phpfwJ45w to uploads/image.jpg

uploads is set to 777.

Is it possible to manually set the path of the temporary folder? e.g.

https://dummydomain.com/tempuploads/

If not then how do I find the full path of the tmp folder or is there some other reason the images are not being uploaded?

I've read it's better to store images into a folder and not into a database table?

```
<?php 
include "connect.php"; 
function UploadOne($fname) 
{ 
$uploaddir = 'http://dummydomain.com/uploads/'; 
if (is_uploaded_file($fname['tmp_name'])) 
{ 
$filname = basename($fname['name']); 
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($fname['name']); 
if (move_uploaded_file ($fname['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
$res = "File " . $filname . " was successfully uploaded and stored.<br>"; 
else 
$res = "Could not move ".$fname['tmp_name']." to ".$uploadfile."<br>"; 
} 
else 
$res = "File ".$fname['name']." failed to upload."; 
return ($res); 
} 
?> 

<body> 
<?php 
if ($_FILES['picture']['name'] != "")   
{ 
$res = UploadOne($_FILES['picture']); 
$filname = $_FILES['picture']['name']; 
echo ($res); 
} 
?> 
<h1>UPLOADING FILES</h1> 
<form name="fupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploads.php" method="post"> 
<input type="file" name="picture" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't specify a http:// URL as $uploaddir but a path relative to the path where the php script is running from.

Also: when using move_uploaded_file() you don't need to know the tmp folder path, it's set by php.ini. Read up [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in tmp_folder or smth like that. You need to set $uploaddir without domainname (it may be the path on your server):

```
 - $uploaddir = 'http://dummydomain.com/uploads/'; 
 + $uploaddir = getcwd() . '/uploads/';
```

It will find /uploads/ directory in the same to running file folder.

Don't store the images in DB! It's bad. :)

Comment: Why store images into DB is bad?

Comment: @Danny Chernyavsky Thanks. It working.

I have a form which stores and then displays a users comments into a database table. I will use this script to allow them to upload images. How do I then display these images automatically? I only want users to see the images they have uploaded. Can someone link to tutorials or tell me what I should search for?

Comment: @Lucio Because, if you'll have too many images, database will be very big and it all can work slow. You wouldn't move it to it's own static server, configured to work correct with static. Okat, AS FOR ME, store images in DB is bad practice.

Comment: @Nullbreaker Yo just need store a link to image in database. If it may be just in text of comment - put tag <img > in correct place, if it's just attachments - create table like comments_images and store image's urls there (commentId => url).

I reccomend use some wisiwyg editor (like redactorjs) that allows to upload images. In such case you will need just do server-side work (move image to correct place), editor will put correct tag inside comment's text.

Comment: Danny Chernyavsky 1. How do I automatically generate the image path after it has been uploaded?

2. Do I then use a variable to write the information into a table?

3. Would I need to use a session to restrict access of the images to the user that uploaded it?

Comment: @Nullbreaker I recommend to try first, and then as your questions :)

1. $uploadfile is a path to your image.
2. Sorry, misunderstood.
3. I don't know your task. If you wish - you can, but, as for me, comments are public information, that's why everybody might have the access to uploaded photos.

Sorry, I need more info about your task. I reccomend to create a separate issue with more info.

Comment: @Danny Chernyavsky Thank you for the advice. I will create a new question with more details.